# Wrap C++ object without going through constructor

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I have a C++ object which inherits from `node::ObjectWrap`. The object itself manages the resource so it accepts it as an argument in a private constructor.

When object is created from Javascript it's quite straightforward:

```
void New(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
  // ...
  auto handleToCustomResource = resolveFromJSArg(args[0]->ToString());
  auto object = new MyObjectWrap(handleToCustomResource);
  object->Wrap(args.This());
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(args.This());
}
```

However it's not clear how to wrap the object when it originates from C++, here is my recent effort:

```
public v8::Local<v8::Object> CreateObject(v8::Isolate *isolate, const char *name) {
  v8::Local<v8::Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
  v8::EscapableHandleScope scope(isolate);

  auto object = new MyObjectWrap(handleToMyCustomResource);

  v8::Local<v8::Object> instance = // eh don't have an instance??

  object->Wrap(instance);

  return scope.Escape(instance);
}
```

How to properly create a JS object so I could use it as an instance for my native object?

One of workarounds I found is to basically have two constructors, one public and one private and then inherit one from another. The public one is available in javascript, while the private is solely used to create an instance for wrapping an existing ObjectWrap object.

```
v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> privTpl = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, PrivateNew);
v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> pubTpl = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, New);

// define prototype

pubTpl->Inherit(privTpl);


exports->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "MyObject"), tpl->GetFunction());
```